# Looking for a short story about a town that's disappearing

Tags: story-identification, horror

I believe there was a child, probably a boy, and he was on the phone talking to people but kept getting disconnected because the town was disappearing slowly street by street. I read this probably sometime in the 1980's, possibly 90's. Thought it was Stephen King but can't find it.